# Need Powershell script to point client machines to new splunk deployment server

Tags: powershell, splunk

Basically, need the script to loop through a list of client servers and

1. Stop splunk
2. Set deploy-poll newDepServer:port
3. Start splunk

Caveat - the commands im trying to run are splunk commands specifically. so, they must run in the splunkuniversalforwader\bin location

I can get the "start" and "stop" to work (I assume because those are windows commands FOR Splunk service ....

However, the set deploy-poll xxx.xxx:port    is getting rejected "not a valid command"

```
$computername = "test_server"

$products = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_product -ComputerName $computername -filter 'Name like "% forwarder%"' | select Caption, InstallLocation

foreach ($product in $products)
{
    $installpath = $product.InstallLocation
}

$installpath += "bin\"

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computername -ScriptBlock { 
    Set-Location "C:\program files\splunkuniversalforwarder\bin"
    & ".\splunk.exe" "stop"
    & ".\splunk.exe" "set deploy-poll xxx.xxx.xxx:xxx"
    & ".\splunk.exe" "start"
} -ArgumentList $installpath
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the quotes around "set deploy-poll xxx.xxx.xxx:xxx" ? it might be treating those as a single argument.

Comment: See following which give info on how to run PS cmdlets remotely : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_requirements?view=powershell-7.3

Comment: @jdweng: WMI works without requiring use of the WinRM service, which I believe is disabled by default. WMI should work even if WinRM isn't available.

Comment: Hey George,

Removing the quotes worked, thanks!!

How do I give you credit?

Comment: @blahblah I'll post it as an answer and you can upvote it and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
& ".\splunk.exe" "set deploy-poll xxx.xxx.xxx:xxx"
```

"set deploy-poll xxx.xxx.xxx:xxx" is being treated as one argument to splunk.exe instead of 3 separate ones. It should work if you change the line to the following:

```
& ".\splunk.exe" set deploy-poll xxx.xxx.xxx:xxx
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered just deploying a new app from your old Deployment Server that updates where every UF should check-in to the new Deployment Server(s)?

This is how I've done it every time I've needed to

Comment: Been thinking about that - the problem is that when it was set up the etc/system/local has the deploymentclient.conf in it ....so, I would need to manually go into each machine and delete it from system/local anyway ...scripting these three commands seemed easier

Comment: Push an app that contains a script that deletes $SPLUNK_HOME/etc/system/local/deploymentclient.conf.  Another app pushed at the same time will contain the replacement deploymentclient.conf file.

Comment: @blahblah - RichG's suggestion is good here: have one app setup with a script that ensures `/$SPLUNK_HOME/etc/system/local/deploymentclient.conf` does not exist. Also deploy (could even be in the same app, if you like) something like `$SPLUNK_HOME/etc/apps/my_deployment_client/local/deploymentclient.conf` that points to the proper place. This also allows you to segment your Deployment Servers if necessary (eg one for Windows Server, one for Linux servers, one for desktops, etc)

Comment: Thanks all, yes, was planning on using the deployment server for sending the script to delete the system/local. But that script got wonky due to weird permissions in environment - so I bailed and went with the above instead. Also, mass deleting a system/local file kinda freaked me out ¯\_(ツ)_/¯